# need to have dynamic divs parallel and text centered

Tags: jquery, html, css, angularjs

```
<div class="ss"> 
 <div ng-repeat="c in size">
         <div ng-repeat="m in p.size"   ng-if="m == c.id">
                <a href="" ng-click="select_size(c.id)" ng-class="{gvborder : allsels == c.id}"><p> {{c.name}} &nbsp;&nbsp;</p></a>
        </div>
  </div>

</div>

    <style>
    .ss{
    text-align:center;
    }
    </style>
```

I need to have the output like 
A B C in one line with text centered.

One important thing is i need to have the **text centered** in the page.

I tried using style:float:left. 
I get the ouput as A B C in one line but my text is not centered. It is floating left.

pLEASE HELP ME

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: We need the OUTPUT HTML/CSS but the first thing to do is **remove the float**. The first rule of centering is "Don't use Float!"

Comment: parallel HOW?? please provide drawing

Comment: parallel what i mean is, should be in one line.

Answer (score 0):

If you're determining the values/text of the dynamic divs through jQuery, you can push all the values into an array, and create a loop that adds all of the values together into one string with a buffer value, ie. a space, that separates all of the values. Then place that string into a div.

```
var $out01="A";
var $out02="B";
var $out03="C";
var $buff=" ";
var array=[$out01,$out02,$out03]
var $con="";

for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
    $con+=array[i];
    if(i!=array.length-1){$con+=$buff;}
}

$('#output').text($con);
```

[See example](https://jsfiddle.net/karljuhlke/kxrfvbkc/)